# How to conserve user setting for hidden dataset for update?

Tags: chart.js

I have hidden datasets (hidden:true).
The user can unhide the dataset by clicking on the legend.
When I now update the dataset the dataset is hidden again (instead of the users unhide).

How can I find out the users setting for hidden, before I update the dataset?
(in the chart is only the original setting stored - or I am wrong?)

chart.js 3.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done through [`chart.getDatasetMeta(index)`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getdatasetmeta-index) as follows:

```
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
...
let hidden = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex).hidden;
```